# How to resize a window in openGL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, scale, viewport

I'm making a game in OpenGL. I have a viewport that is multiplied by a transformation matrix using `glOrthof()`. I'm almost done with the game, but I've made a last minute decision to scale everything down a little bit to increase visibility. I have included a diagram depicting how my screen is currently set up (the black box) and how I would like to scale it (the red box).

[image: window]

given the width and height of the black box, and `x` and `y` in the diagram, would it be possible to adjust the viewport, or perhaps do some sort of matrix multiplication to increase the window size?

I don't want to actually scale the game, I just want to increase the size of the window (which I guess will ultimately scale the game, but I want to preserve the relative scale).

right now, this is how I'm setting up my view:

```
glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(-backingWidth/2.0, backingWidth/2.0, -backingHeight/2.0, backingHeight/2.0, -1.0f, 1.0f);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

where `backingWidth`, and `backingHeight` are the width and height of the black box respectively.

I'm pretty new to OpenGL, so all help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused by all the mentions mentions of scaling. To put this simply, if I held up a ruler to my screen, would the same object appear larger in the red window, or appear the same size? Or should the red window contain the exact same content, just stretched to be larger?

Comment: It would appear smaller, basically everything would be smaller. But the sizes would be the same relative to everything else, because everything would be scaled down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see more area in the same viewport size, you can just increase the values given to glOrthof.

If you multiply the top/left/bottom/right of glOrthof to be twice as large, then you will see twice as much in each direction, and everything will be half the original size in each direction, because you're putting twice as much content into the same number of pixels.

You can multiply glOrthof by any scale factor you want.

==EDIT==

Sorry, I noticed that you want to only scale X to the right, and not about the center. In that case leave the `left` attribute the same, and just add more to the `right` value of glOrthof.

Comment: hmm, why doesn't `GL_POINT` scale when you do this?

Comment: GL_POINTs are kind of a weird hacky construct that doesn't behave like other OpenGL primitives (same for GL_LINES). Points are drawn directly in screen space, so their size is always glPointSize, regardless of any scale transform. If you're worried about this, it would be better to use textured quads instead of points.